# Alternative to Static Abstract Property/Method

Tags: c#, networking

Since trying to use them will cause an error what is the workaround to get the same effect as them?

My Base Class:

```
public abstract class IPacket
{
    public abstract int Identifier { get; set; }

    public abstract void Handle();
}
```

Child Class:

```
public class DoSomething : IPacket
{
    public override int Identifier
    {
        get
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public override void Handle()
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

Incoming Packet Routing:

```
Dictionary<Byte, IPacket> Packets = new Dictionary<byte, IPacket>
    {
        {DoSomething.Identifier, DoSomething} // <-- Not Possible
    };

Packets[ID].Handle();
```

Basically I get a packet from Server which contains an Identifier. I use this identifier to find the handler for that packet from a dictionary and pass the packet to it's handler.

Comment: Why don't you allocate one DoSomething before you try to put it in the dictionary?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Packets.add(xxx.Identifier,xxx);` given `xxx` is of type `Ipacket` ?

Comment: @user61852 Well that is what is being done.

Comment: @LRNAB I don't see that code in your question. On the other hand I don't know C#, just Java, and perhaps the operation is implied.

Comment: @user61852 `{DoSomething.Identifier, DoSomething}`

Comment: @LRNAB DoSomething is a class. You need to instantiate a new DoSomething in order to add it to the dictionary. In order to access that DoSomething's Identifier, you must instantiate the DoSomething before adding it to the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you dispatch `Handle` on an identifier and not on packet object's class, I don't see any benefit in having `Handle` as a method of packet objects.

Think about some `PacketProcessor` that handles packets of certain type, and a `Dictionary<Identifier, PacketProcessor>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DoSomething newSomething = new DoSomething();
Dictionary<int, IPacket> Packets = new Dictionary<int, IPacket>
{
    { newSomething.Identifier, newSomething } // <-- Possible
};
```

IPacket as an abstract class and not an interface isn't intuitive naming.

```
// Alternatively,
public interface IPacket
{
    int Identifier { get; }
    void Handle();
}

public class DoSomething : IPacket
{
    public int Identifier { get; set; }
    public void Handle() { }
}
```

...

```
int id = 1;
Dictionary<int, IPacket> Packets = new Dictionary<int, IPacket>
{
    { id, new DoSomething { Identifier = id } }
};
```